# Magento Multi domain & country specific domain endings

Tags: multistore, multidomain, magento-ce, name, domain

I'm new on Magento and in this time I'm studying how build an e-commerce site with Magento CE.

I read some guides and wiki, but there is a thing I don't understand.
When we say that magento can manage the multi site, and multi domain in configuration we put the name and domain for all the stores domain.

I ask you, Can I create the structure of all magento sites in one magento installation based on different domain name?

*For example:*

1. site one: italian language and domain .it;
2. site two: english language and domain .uk;
3. site three: french language and domain .fr;
4. site .... etc.

Please answer my question it's very important for me and if possible please tell me the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can set this up. You simply need to have one `store-view` for each domain. These can be setup under `System->Manage Stores`.

I am not sure 100% of your set-up but you can have one website, one store and then one store-view for each domain.

Then under `System->Configuration->Web` you can assign each store view with it's own url using the drop down in the left hand side to change store view.