# Magento multi site

Tags: magento-1.9, multidomain

I have 2 sites `site.com.au` and `www.example.com.au`

This is a multi website set up on one magento instance.
`site.com.au` works as expected, you can login and add items to the cart.
For `site.com.au` I configured like this

```
cookie path = /
cookie domain = site.com.au
```

`www.example.com.au` I have no sessions. i.e cannot login or add anything to the cart

for `www.example.com.au` I have it configured like this

```
cookie path = /
cookie domain = .example.com.au
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento Multi domain](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28721/magento-multi-domain)

Comment: is your cookie name correct?